# Crash when create Swing application window

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, eclipse-plugin

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f475c7302b7, pid=7578, tid=0x00007f475e12e700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_171-b11) (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-b11)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.171-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0+0x4e2b7]  gdk_display_open+0x57
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/usuari/eclipse/hs_err_pid7578.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

**Systen Ubuntu Xenial.
I've tried -nosplash and ulimit -c unlimited. I try too add -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla in eclipse.ini.
But it crash when create a Swing application window.**

I've tried reinstall

libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 - GDK Pixbuf library

libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common - GDK Pixbuf library - data files

hs_err_pid7578.log

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f475c7302b7, pid=7578, tid=0x00007f475e12e700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_171-b11) (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-b11)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.171-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0+0x4e2b7]  gdk_display_open+0x57
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f47c5605000):  JavaThread "ModalContext" [_thread_in_native, id=7667, stack(0x00007f475e02e000,0x00007f475e12f000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000114

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x00007f479448a010, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x00007f475e12bae0, RBP=0x00007f475e12baf0, RSI=0x00007f475c7300b0, RDI=0x00007f479448a010
R8 =0x00007f47944961e0, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x000000000000000b, R11=0x000000000000000e
R12=0x00007f475d6713a0, R13=0x00007f47941e8b30, R14=0x00007f4794464be8, R15=0x0000000000000001
RIP=0x00007f475c7302b7, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000006
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f475e12bae0)
0x00007f475e12bae0:   000100000100ffff 0001000000000000
0x00007f475e12baf0:   002000007f007463 0025000000000000
0x00007f475e12bb00:   624f472d62694c47 00007f007463656a
0x00007f475e12bb10:   0000000000000020 0000000000000025
0x00007f475e12bb20:   65706f2d382d6176 646d612d6b646a6e
0x00007f475e12bb30:   0000000000000000 0000000000000068
0x00007f475e12bb40:   6e65706f2d382d61 36646d612d6b646a
0x00007f475e12bb50:   00007f47941e8b30 00007f4794464be8
0x00007f475e12bb60:   0000000000000001 00007f47cccad53c
0x00007f475e12bb70:   00007f47944869f0 0000000000000000
```

Comment: What has this to do with Eclipse plugins? Is this just a plain Java Swing application your are running from within Eclipse?

Comment: I've installed the Windows Builder plugin first and then I just create an application window.